# Panda pivot_table with only column total and no row total

Tags: pandas, pivot

I want to have grand total for columns *ONLY* and not for the rows.  It seems the margins flag will give me both row and column total:

`pivot_operation=pd.pivot_table(df_operation,index=["Name"],values=["Hours"], columns=["Workdate"],aggfunc=[np.sum],margins=True,margins_name='Grand Total')`

And I get

```
Hours
Workdate    02-03   02-04   02-05   02-06   02-07   Grand Total
Name                        
Joe              8.0    8.0     8.0     8.0     8.0     40.0
Mary             8.5    8.5     8.5     8.5     8.5     42.5
Grand Total     16.5    16.5    16.5    16.5    16.5    82.5
```

Where I only want the Columns Grand Total without Row Grand total

```
Hours
Workdate    02-03   02-04   02-05   02-06   02-07   Grand Total
Name                        
Joe              8.0    8.0     8.0     8.0     8.0     40.0
Mary             8.5    8.5     8.5     8.5     8.5     42.5
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: one option would be to set margins to False, and create a new column 'Grand Total' by using the sum function, and set the axis=1

Answer (score 3):

For now, I could work around this by removing the last row using iloc function() after creating the pivot with margin. `aggfunc=[np.sum],margins=True,margins_name='Grand Total').iloc[:-1,:]`

Comment: Hi , if its sortout this issue , please let me know , how to do it